# Создание конструктора в Java

Tags: java, ооп, конструктор, инкапсуляция

Прошу помощи в понимании аспектов конструктора. Пример, у меня есть какой-то класс `SomeClass` и какой-то объект `SomeObject`, при инициализации нового экземпляра этого класса, я передаю в него выборочные данные из `SomeObject`, делаю `new SomeClass(someObject.getId(), someObject.getSomeField(), ..., someObject.getAnotherField());`

Вопрос в следующем: Можно-ли при инициализации передать в конструктор объект и сделать выборку полей внутри конструктора как показано в **Варианте 2**, если нельзя то почему и чем это черевато?

```
public class SomeClass {
    private Long someId;
    private String someField;
    .....
    private String anotherField;
```

**конструктор вариант 1.**

```
public SomeClass(Long id, String someField,..., String anotherField) {
    this.id = id;
    this.someField =  someField;
    ....
    this.anotherField = anotherField;
    }
```

**конструктор вариант 2.**

```
public SomeClass(SomeObject someObject) {
        this.id = someObject.getId();
        this.someField =  someObject.getSomeField();
        ....
        this.anotherField = someObject.getAnotherField();
        }
```

Comment: Вариант 1 менее предпочтителен из-за большого числа аргументов. Если не хотите передавать в SomeClass объект, то лучше создать builder для класса.

Comment: Лучше используйте паттерн Builder

Comment: @maxim, Я не про-то что не хочу, лично по мне это наоборот более удобный вариант, но мне просто хотелось бы знать, не является ли это ошибочным действием, так сказать, не нарушаю ли я "фен-шуй")))

Comment: @AndreyPopov Sonar сочтет, что от вашего кода попахивает, если в конструкторе будет много параметров: https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-107
Передавая же объект внутрь конструктора, вы делаете этот класс связанным с классом SomeObject. Связанность через конструкторы эти типичная схема того, что называют dependency injection

Comment: ошибся ссылкой, там правило на метод, но про конструктор тоже есть похожее, честно честно.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ключевой вопрос в следующем: класс `SomeClass` предназначен исключительно для работы с экземплярами `SomeObject` или это некий абстрактный расчетный класс?

Приведу пример. Есть метод, вычисляющий объем параллелепипеда

```
int getVolume(int x1, int y1, int z1, int x2, int y2, int z2)
```

и есть объект класса `Кирпич`, где одними из параметров являются координаты кирпича

```
class Brick {
  ............
  int getX1() { .... }
  int getY1() { .... }
  int getZ1() { .... }
  int getX2() { .... }
  int getY2() { .... }
  int getZ2() { .... }
}
```

Вы можете, объявить метод, вычисляющий объем кирпича

```
int getVolume(Brick brick)
```

но тогда вы не сможете вычислить объем штабеля из кирпичей. Т.е. в данном случае, передавать объект не стоит и лучше передать набор параметров.

А вот если у вас метод вычисляет прочность кирпича, то тут лучше передать весь объект. Т.к. прочность можно считать только для кирпичей.

Но, для вычисления объема можно использовать интерфейс `Параллелепипед`. И передавать в метод экземпляр **интерфейса**. Тогда в метод можно передавать любой объект, поддерживающий этот интерфейс

Comment: да, класс `SomeClass` в моем случае предназначен исключительно для работы с экземплярами `SomeObject`

Comment: Передачу объекта как параметр часто используют в копирующих конструкторах.